# Disable cursor focus for read only textbox while using tab key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using readonly textbox. I want to focus on input textbox only if that is editable. If that is non-editable, How should i disable focus for the particular textbox.

Comment: Set `tabindex="-1"` for the textbox when it's not editable.

Comment: to eradicate click action you may add too : [readonly] {pointer-events:none;}

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```html
<input type="text" value="test" onfocus="this.blur()" readonly="readonly">
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It worked for me :)
But I am hoping for some css based solution 
except this solution ->>>> tab-index = -1; 
Because tab-index doesn't work in case of touch devices keyboards (specially in ios)

Answer (score 0):

set `tabindex = "-1"`

and keep one selector css `input:read-only {pointer-events: none;}`

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to set the input as `disabled` which would prevent focusing it and skip it in tab navigation

```
<input disabled="disabled" />
```

You can add styles to override the disabled styles

Comment: but remember that the field won't be submitted with the form if you set disabled...